# Setting a body background image in MuiThemeProvider

Tags: material-ui

I have a react app with Material UI. I know how to set the theme's default background color on body. However, I want to set a background image instead. How can I accomplish this?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: ???
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using CssBaseline you can apply a global style through theme overrides and set the backgroundImage for body e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/v30yq681ql. You should be able to set the global style through any component that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for me

```
...
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ...
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundImage:
            "url(https://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/gradient-background.jpg)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Instead this worked

```
...
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ...
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          backgroundImage: "url(https://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/gradient-background.jpg)",
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
```